# Ktor: cannot resolve JacksonSerializer

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to setup ktor http client in commonMain module of Kotlin Multiplatform project (as described here https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/features/json-feature.html), but cannot resolve dependency to it:

```
    val client = HttpClient {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = JacksonSerializer()
        }
    }
```

Gradle version: 4.7.

Here is build.gradle for common module:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

    kotlin {
        targets {
            // Change to `presets.iosArm64` to deploy the app to iPhone
            fromPreset(presets.iosX64, 'ios') {
                compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
            }
        }
        sourceSets {
            commonMain.dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$coroutines_version"
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version"

                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-jackson:$ktor_version"
            }
            commonTest {
                dependencies {
                    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common"
                    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common"
                }
            }
            iosMain {
                dependencies {
                    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$coroutines_version"
                    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version"

                    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
                    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-ios:$ktor_version"
                    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-ios:$ktor_version"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use jackson on ios as it is JVM specific. On ios only Kotlinx.serialization works.